# Deploying Django code (which needs Selenium) to heroku - Python

Tags: python, django, selenium, heroku

I have a website made using Django, click a button on the website triggers a scraper to start. This scraper uses selenium. I have added the following two build packs needed for selenium to my heroku app:

1) https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver

2) https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.binary_location='/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome'
os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN", "chromedriver")
browser=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN", "chromedriver"),chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

But yet it fails to find the chromedriver and throws the error chromedriver needs to be in PATH, how to fix this issue? Where is the chromedriver executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to comment you the link, where I previously answered this question, but I don't have enough rep to comment, so anywho here you go..

Set the following path using `heroku congfig:set` command

`heroku config:set CHROMEDRIVER_PATH=/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver` and
`heroku config:set GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN=/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome`

Verify the paths using `heroku config` command

You can use this snippet to configure your definition

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def load_chrome_driver(proxy):

      options = Options()

      options.binary_location = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN')

      options.add_argument('--headless')
      options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
      options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
      options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
      options.add_argument('--proxy-server='+proxy)

      return webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=str(os.environ.get('CHROMEDRIVER_PATH')), chrome_options=options)
```

I'm using proxies, but you can probably avoid that.